# Can't create VPN due to blocked ports

Tags: vpn, port-forwarding

I want to be able to access my home network using VPN (preferably OpenVPN). The problem is that port 1194 is blocked by my current ISP and the only other ISP available does the same thing. The router is a DLink DWR-921; I connect to the internet via GSM (4G).

Are there any options available? Could I use a non-standard port that's not blocked? Will this have any impact? The VPN server would be a Synology DS414.

Answer (score 1):

Simply configure the VPN to use a different port. Better still, you can do this with your router. Leave the NAS VPN port at 1194 and configure the NAT rule on the router to expose a different port externally, one that the ISP allows. Then configure the VPN client to that port.

Alternatively, rather than using OpenVPN, simply use PUTTY to connect to SSH on the NAS with port forwarding (AKA tunnelling) configured..

Comment: I'll try this and see if it works. I want a VPN simply because I want to access more than just my NAS.

Comment: It didn't work (putty doesn't work either). I connect to the internet via a 4G connection, so the IP my router received is 10.x.x.x, which is not public (it's in an APN). I'm not sure what I can do about that.

Comment: That's odd. When I used a 4G router recently because my broadband was down, I got a publicly routeable IP as expected. That's down to your provider. Not sure there is much you can do. Who is the provider?

Comment: Vodafone. The alternatives in my country aren't better in this regard.